# Hibernate - problems with lock

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm questioning my implementation of the lock in various scenarios and I'd like to have some suggestion by user more expert than me.
I'm using two support class, named HibernateUtil and StorageManager.

**HibernateUtil**

Simply returns a singleton instance of session factory; obviously, it creates the session factory on the first call.

**StorageManager**

Encloses the common operations between the various entities. On its creation, it gets the session factory from HibernateUtil and store it into a static variable.
This class implements the session-per-request (or maybe session-per-operation) pattern and for this reason for every kind of request it basically does this things in sequence:

1. open a new session (from the session factory previously stored)
2. begin a new transaction
3. execute the specific request (depends on the specific methods of StorageManager invoked
4. commit transaction
5. close session

Of course, comment on this style are really appreciated.

Then, there are basically 3 categories of operations that implements point 3

*Insert, Update or Delete entity*

```
session.save(entity); 
// OR session.update(entity) OR session.delete(entity)
session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.UPGRADE).lock(entity);
```

*Get entity*

```
T entity = (T) session.byId(type).with(LockOptions.READ).load(id);
// There are other forms of get, but they are pretty similar
```

*Get list*

```
List<T> l = session.createCriteria(type).list();
// Same here, various but similar forms of get list
```

Again, don't know if it is the right way to implement the various actions.
Also, and this is the real problem, whenever an error occurred, it is impossible to access to the datastore in any way, even from command line, until I manually stop the application that caused the problem. How can I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

---

### EDIT

**Some more code**
This is the code for the parts listed above.

```
private void createTransaction()  // Parts 1 and 2 of the above list
{
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    transaction = null;
    try
    {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    }
    catch (HibernateException exception)
    {
        if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void commitTransaction() // Part 4 of the above list
{
    try
    {
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException exception)
    {
        if (transaction != null) transaction.rollback();
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void closeSession() // Part 5 of the above list
{
    try
    {
        // if (session != null)
        {
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }
    }
    catch (HibernateException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void update(T entity) // Example usage for part 3 of the above list
{
    try
    {
        this.createTransaction();
        session.update(entity);
        // session.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.UPGRADE).lock(entity);
        this.commitTransaction();
    }
    catch (HibernateException exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        this.closeSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error case (the real problem) indicates you are not following the typical transaction usage idiom (from the [Session Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html)):

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    //do some work, point 3
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
    throw e;
} finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

Note the catch and finally blocks which ensure any database resources are released in case of an error. (*)

I'm not sure why you would want to lock a database record (LockOptions.UPGRADE) after you have changed it (insert, update or delete entity). You normally lock a database record before you (read and) update it so that you are sure you get the latest data and no other open transactions using the same database record can interfere with the (read and) update.

Locking makes little sense for insert operations since the default transaction isolation level is "read committed"(1) which means that when a transaction inserts a record, that record only becomes visible to other database transactions AFTER the transaction that inserts the record commits. I.e. before the transaction commit, other transactions cannot select and/or update the newly "not yet comitted" inserted record.

(1) Double check this to make sure. Search for "hibernate.connection.isolation" in the [Hibernate configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html) chapter. Value should be "2" as shown in the [Java Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED) constant field values.

(*) There is a nasty corner case when a database connection is lost after a database record is locked. In this case, the client cannot commit or rollback (since the connection is broken) and the database server might keep the lock on the record forever. A good database server will unlock records locked by a database connection that is broken and discarded (and rollback any open transaction for that broken database connection), but there is no guarantee (e.g. how and when will a database server discover a broken database connection?). This is one of the reasons to use database record locks sparsely: try to use them only when the application(s) using the database records cannot prevent concurrent/simultaneous updates to the same database record.

Comment: Actually, I use try/catch blocks at all levels. I posted some more code in the EDIT part. 
About the lock part, I'm just a newbie to Hibernate and I think I implemented it the wrong way. I thought that, because the `buildLockRequest` comes always before the commit transaction, it actually lock the entity BEFORE doing stuff on it. Am I wrong? What is the right way?
About the lock on insert operation, I thought that it was necessary because some values of entities have unique constraints: what happens, for example, if two different users try to register with the same email address or nickname?

Comment: @tigerjack89 About the code in the EDIT part: there is still a code path where the transaction does not get rolled back when "session.update" fails. Just follow the idiom in "part 3" and remove all other helper methods for the other parts - they are not actually helping. The upgrade lock works as you (and I) describe but in your question you place the lock after session.save/update/delete which is after "doing stuff on it". As for the insert with the same email-address: one of the users will get an error saying the email-address is already in use - there is little you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks again. About the code, I don't know if I see your point. Does it mean that the `session.update` can raise an exception even before the `transaction.commit`? If this is the case, I've to add the `transaction.rollback` in the catch clause of part 3, right? Or obv I've to refactorize all the code.

Comment: About the lock, I thought that the order wasn't important as long as the operations are executed before the commit. I was wrong obv. But now the problem is that, iirc, I can't lock the entity because, before the insert it doesn't have an id (that is autogenerated from the database). So, ultimately, I have to delete the lock for the insert and get operations and change the order for the update and delete ones?

Comment: @tigerjack89 Yes, session.update can throw an exception. It helps if you always assume any statement can throw a NullPointerException. Even if that happens, your code must close resources (in this case transactions and sessions). Also, your helper methods are catching exceptions without rethrowing which will actually cause NullPointerExceptions in "part 3" and makes it hard to debug. You can keep the helper methods but you'll see that after rethrow-changes, you might as well just follow the idiom.

Comment: @tigerjack89 Indeed, there is no lock before insert. But you will need extra code to detect "duplicate nickname/email-address" and handle that case gracefully (instead of showing a stack-trace to the user). For read/get only operations a lock is usually not needed since you read committed data. For update operations a lock might be needed to read latest data (e.g. access-count) and update it (e.g. access-count + 1). But it is only needed if two transactions can run at the same time and use the same database record and require no interference during the (read and) update operation.

Comment: thanks for your help van, really appreciated. And all these comments made me understand a lot issues that I was having. As a final note, it seems that my helper method are actually useless; indeed, the whole StorageManager class seems unnecessary and can cause a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Spring Hibernate/JPA support. You can then have a singleton SessionFactory and transaction boundaries are explicitly set by using @Transactional.

The session is automatically managed by the Transactioninterceptor so no matter how many DAOs you call from a service, all of those will use the same thread-bound Session.

The actual Spring configuration is much easier than having to implement your current solution.

If you don;t plan on using Spring then you have to make sure you are actually implementing the session-per-request patterns. If you are using [session-per-operation anti-pattern](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-operation) then you won't be able to include two or more operations into a single unit-of-work.

The [session-per-request pattern](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#d0e1198) requires an external interceptor/AOP aspect to open/close and bind the current session to the current calling thread. You might want to configure this property also:

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

so that Hibernate can bind the current Session into the current thread local storage.

Comment: thank you for your time Vlad. Actually, I don't know much about Spring; it is on my todo list for next year. Also, because it is an homework assignment, I have no time at all to learn it now.
In which part do you think my code is wrong/difficult?

Comment: Sure Vlad, as always; and as always, thanks for your time :). Btw, reading the code again, it seems that you're right; I think I'm using the session-per-operation anti-pattern. I think that it is usually bad for business applications, but it can simplify some stuffs in my case. Am I wrong? So, what is the best way to lock database entries in this case?

Comment: You don't need to lock entries in the db. You have a session management issue not a locking problem. I already gave you two solutions so it's up to you which one you want to use, if any.

Comment: Well, from the answer I didn't understand what is the actual issue with the session. I mean, I understand the how to part, but not the why. Also, is there any solution for continue to use the session-per-operation antipattern (that is what I'm using now I think)? Also, if you can, take a look at the edited part in the question.